# Add a class to Angular 2 Material component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to add a class (or a set of styles) to `MdTabHeader` defined inside `MdTabGroup` of angular/material2 in response to an event through a service. How do I achieve that in a proper way without using things like `/deep/`, `getElementsByTagName`, etc?

Angular Material's MdTabGroup:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
      The <em>best</em> pasta
    </ng-template>
    <h1>Best pasta restaurants</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
      <md-icon>thumb_down</md-icon> The worst sushi
    </ng-template>
    <h1>Terrible sushi restaurants</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

The `md-tab-header` element shows up while inspecting DOM. I want to add a class to that element through an Angular Service.

Comment: I'm aware you can't. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1276

Comment: @DawidWiniarczyk Yes, I went through this thread before posting this question. But that's a closed issue. And what if I want to use methods described on that thread to add a class through Angular not through SCSS as I want the style to be applied only under certain conditions.